# Can anyone tell me the name of this font?

Tags: font-identification

I downloaded this font from www.dafont.com several weeks ago. My computer crashed and I've been trying to reinstall all my old fonts. I've used font identification websites with no luck. Is anyone able to tell me the name of this font? Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brandon, Welcome to GDSE! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Went to Dafont, clicked on Calligraphy style, sorted by popularity and... third given result did match!   
I think you probably spent more time typing your question than actually doing the research by yourself.  
So I'm not going to give the answer, instead I suggest you give a try to this very basic research...

Answer (score 1):

The font's name is [**Black Diamonds**](http://www.dafont.com/black-diamonds.font?text=homestyle%20broccoli%20cheddar%20soup).

[image]